# Referencing AST nodes after construction with Visitor pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a memory management question. For [one of my projects](https://github.com/blorente/naylang) I am building an interpreter for a small programming language. One of the first steps is to model and build  an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

As of now, I'm using smart pointers to manage the lifetime of nodes, and I figured that every parent node is the owner of it's children, **but** it also must be shared with the environment (for example, to know which part of the tree a method's body belongs to) and with the garbage collector, which must keep a list of all references to enact the naïve mark and sweep algorithm. Therefore, I am using `std::shared_ptr` to keep track of the references. For instance, here's an example of a `Block` node, which basically represents a lambda expression:

```
#ifndef NAYLANG_BLOCK_H
#define NAYLANG_BLOCK_H

#include <model/ast/expressions/Expression.h>
#include <model/ast/declarations/Declaration.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace naylang {

#define BlockPtr std::shared_ptr<Block>

class Block : public Expression {

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Statement>> _body;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Declaration>> _params;

public:

    Block() = default;

    void accept(Evaluator &evaluator) override;

    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Statement>> &body() const;
    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Declaration>> &params() const;

    void addStatement(std::shared_ptr<Statement> statement);
    void addParameter(std::shared_ptr<Declaration> param);
};

} // end namespace naylang

#endif //NAYLANG_BLOCK_H
```

As you can see, this node is the owner of all it's parameters and body expressions, and has accessors so that the `Evaluator` can traverse the tree.

Now, the problem comes when trying to have nodes that are bound **at evaluation time** to other nodes, for example:

```
#ifndef NAYLANG_REQUEST_H
#define NAYLANG_REQUEST_H

#include <model/ast/expressions/Expression.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <model/ast/declarations/MethodDeclaration.h>

namespace naylang {

class Request : public Expression {

    std::string _name;
    std::vector<ExpressionPtr> _params;

    // We use naked pointers because we don't want to worry
    // about memory management, and there is no ownership
    // with the declaration.
    const MethodDeclaration *_binding;

public:

    Request(const std::string &methodName);
    Request(const std::string &methodName, const std::vector<ExpressionPtr> params);

    void accept(Evaluator &evaluator) override;

    void bindTo(const MethodDeclaration *_binding);

    const std::string &method() const;
    const std::vector<ExpressionPtr> &params() const;
    const MethodDeclaration &declaration() const;
};

} // end namespace naylang

#endif //NAYLANG_REQUEST_H
```

As you can see, `bindTo()` is called when a `BindingEvaluator` (subclass of `Evaluator`) evaluates a Request object, long after it's constructed. However, I am really not sure about what the `_binding` parameter should look like. Here's a part of the `Evaluator` interface:

```
#ifndef NAYLANG_EVALUATOR_H
#define NAYLANG_EVALUATOR_H

#include <model/ast/Statement.h>

namespace naylang {

class Request;
class Block;

class Evaluator {

public:

    Evaluator() = default;
    virtual ~Evaluator() = default;

    // Methods left blank to be overridden by the subclasses.
    // For example, a Binding Evaluator might be only interested in
    // evaluating VariableReference and Request Statements

    virtual void evaluate(Request &expression) {}
    virtual void evaluate(Block &expression) {}
};    
}
#endif //NAYLANG_EVALUATOR_H
```

Here's my rationale:

- The reference should be polymorphic, and therefore should be some kind of pointer.
- The reference does **not** denote ownership, and therefore it should not be a `std::shared_ptr`.
- In addition, we need the Visitor pattern, so every node has the function `void accept(Evaluator &evaluator);`. As a node cannot return a `shared_ptr`of itself, we cannot change the interface to something like `virtual void evaluate(std::shared_ptr<Request> &expression) {}`.

Thus, naked pointers. I really want to get this right before moving on, because it's a ton of code to change every time I rethink it (ASTs are verbose...)

Thank you in advance.